Could you critique my statements below about connection between mind and reality?
I've thought about reality and how it connects to the mind. Starting from the only thing we can be certain about, our existence, and principle of causality. With those I've come up with the below statements:

Reality is an environment, where the mind operates.
Because I am conscious, I must exist.
If I exist, there must be at least one cause for my existence.
If I exist and there is a cause for my existence, there is a substrate on which my mind exists and operates and laws that govern my mind.
From the above I propose that the reality in I operate is the same as the one that governs the mind.

Is it true that only and only if 5. is true can we upgrade our mind beyond its current limits? Or is it possible to improve the human mind, to for example be faster, even if the laws that govern the mind are not the same as the ones that govern the reality in which it operates?
To give an example, if in the future we make VR indistinguishable from reality, then in that VR our mind would not operate on the same laws as the reality in which we would operate, that is virtual reality.
Could you give your opinion on the above principles, thank you.
EDIT: I've replaced 'our' with 'my' and 'we' with 'I', as suggested by Mauro ALLEGRANZA.

There are lots of "little details" to be discussed (in fact, the discussion last since 600 BCE in Ancient Greece): there is mind, Ok, and mind is real. But maybe the only "reality" is mind intself, contra 1.


is a form of cogito: mind is real and thus mind exists. "We" are our mind and thus we exists. As above: maybe "we" is "I".


@MauroALLEGRANZA I've replaced it with me, but I don't think that changes the conclusion. Maybe reality is the mind itself, yet that does not change anything, because above definition of reality only states that whatever reality is is where we operate. Operate meaning that we can 'do stuff' there.

@LaukyS, this forum is best for asking questions about philosophic writings. It's so so good for dicussion, or for presenting own ideas that are not related to specific writings, so I vote to close this question.

A computer program operates in a different environment from the hardware of the computer it is running on, and it can be improved in a manner entirely distinct from improving the hardware. So your point 5 is not necessary to mind improvement.

Your thoughts are basically concerned with the mind–body problem.
Your principles:

1. Reality is an environment, where the mind operates.

Reality is the sum or aggregate of all that is real or existent within the universe, as opposed to that which is only imaginary, nonexistent or nonactual.
But the mind can operate on the grounds of, or take account of imaginary, nonexistent or nonactual facts. So we must "enlarge" this concept of reality in order for this principle to be accurate. You could use a definition like Anaximander's first principle, Aristotle's unmoved mover, Stoic's pneuma, or TAO.

2. Because we are conscious, we must exist.

Consciousness, at its simplest, is awareness of internal and external existence.
I suppose that for every conscious being (having awareness of), self-existence is self-evident by definition.

3. If we exist, there must be at least one cause for our existence.

Causality is an influence by which one event, process, state, or object (a cause) contributes to the production of another event, process, state, or object (an effect) where the cause is partly responsible for the effect, and the effect is partly dependent on the cause.
Here, things start to get really complicated. Although - for some - causality may appear to be a rather straightforward concept, it is not. Nearly all philosophers - in one way or another - have a differentiated view of causality. As a food for though I recommend to read this. I also recommend my answer to another post. What I want to say - in simple words - is that what you seem to think of as an external thing (the cause), may in fact be an internal disposition towards life itself; so that "must" may be the effect of being in the intellectual level.

4. If we exist and there is a cause for our existence, there is a substrate on which the mind exists and operates and laws govern the
mind.

Since you talk about laws - in the context of a substrate - I assume you are talking about physical laws; and not philosophical principles. Here you are making the assumptions a) that [the] causality [of existence] operates and/or is inherent in a substrate, that is basically physical and b) that the mind is enclosed or limited to this substrate. And although I could cope with a) (but  as a manifestation and not as an inherent property), b) is in fact the mind–body problem.

5. From the above I propose that the reality in I operate is the same as the one that governs the mind.

This is basically principle 4, phrased with different words. So, summing up, I do not see that this conclusion follows. My view is that the mind cannot be reduced to a specific (objective) substrate; it operates in many levels, encompassing many realities; it's a subjective journey longing to find The objective.

@Scott Rowe, you are right, I was indeed a little puzzled on how to structure appearance ... I fixed it.
